# How to set up executor IPs inside Docker containers?

Tags: java, apache-spark, docker

The last 3 days I tried to setup a Docker machine with 3 components:
A Spark Master, a Spark Worker and a Driver (Java) Application

When starting the driver OUTSIDE from docker, everything works fine. However Starting all three components leads to an port-firewall-host-nightmare

To keep it (at first) simple I use docker-compose - this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
driver:
  hostname: driver
  image: driverimage
  command: -Dexec.args="0 192.168.99.100" -Dspark.driver.port=7001 -Dspark.driver.host=driver -Dspark.executor.port=7006 -Dspark.broadcast.port=15001 -Dspark.fileserver.port=15002 -Dspark.blockManager.port=15003 -Dspark.broadcast.factory=org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory
  ports:
    - 10200:10200 # Module REST Port
    - 4040:4040 # Web UI (Spark)
    - 7001:7001 # Driver Port (Spark)
    - 15001:15001 # Broadcast (Spark)
    - 15002:15002 # File Server (Spark)
    - 15003:15003 # Blockmanager (Spark)
    - 7337:7337 # Shuffle? (Spark)
  extra_hosts:
    - sparkmaster:192.168.99.100
    - sparkworker:192.168.99.100
  environment:
    SPARK_LOCAL_IP: 192.168.99.100
    #SPARK_MASTER_OPTS: "-Dspark.driver.port=7001 -Dspark.fileserver.port=7002 -Dspark.broadcast.port=7003 -Dspark.replClassServer.port=7004 -Dspark.blockManager.port=7005 -Dspark.executor.port=7006 -Dspark.ui.port=4040 -Dspark.broadcast.factory=org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory"
    #SPARK_WORKER_OPTS: "-Dspark.driver.port=7001 -Dspark.fileserver.port=7002 -Dspark.broadcast.port=7003 -Dspark.replClassServer.port=7004 -Dspark.blockManager.port=7005 -Dspark.executor.port=7006 -Dspark.ui.port=4040 -Dspark.broadcast.factory=org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory"
    SPARK_JAVA_OPTS: "-Dspark.driver.port=7001 -Dspark.fileserver.port=7002 -Dspark.broadcast.port=15001 -Dspark.replClassServer.port=7004 -Dspark.blockManager.port=7005 -Dspark.executor.port=7006 -Dspark.ui.port=4040 -Dspark.broadcast.factory=org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory"

sparkmaster:
  extra_hosts:
    - driver:192.168.99.100
  image: gettyimages/spark
  command: /usr/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master -h sparkmaster
  hostname: sparkmaster
  environment:
    SPARK_CONF_DIR: /conf
    MASTER: spark://sparkmaster:7077
    SPARK_LOCAL_IP: 192.168.99.100
    SPARK_JAVA_OPTS:  "-Dspark.broadcast.factory=org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory"
    SPARK_WORKER_OPTS: "-Dspark.broadcast.factory=org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory"
    SPARK_MASTER_OPTS: "-Dspark.driver.port=7001 -Dspark.fileserver.port=7002 -Dspark.broadcast.port=7003 -Dspark.replClassServer.port=7004 -Dspark.executor.port=7006 -Dspark.ui.port=4040 -Dspark.broadcast.factory=org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory"
    #SPARK_WORKER_OPTS: "-Dspark.driver.port=7001 -Dspark.fileserver.port=7002 -Dspark.broadcast.port=7003 -Dspark.replClassServer.port=7004 -Dspark.blockManager.port=7005 -Dspark.executor.port=7006 -Dspark.ui.port=4040 -Dspark.broadcast.factory=org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory"
    #SPARK_JAVA_OPTS: "-Dspark.driver.port=7001 -Dspark.fileserver.port=7002 -Dspark.broadcast.port=7003 -Dspark.replClassServer.port=7004 -Dspark.blockManager.port=7005 -Dspark.executor.port=7006 -Dspark.ui.port=4040 -Dspark.broadcast.factory=org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory"
  expose:
    - 7001
    - 7002
    - 7003
    - 7004
    - 7005
    - 7006
    - 7077
    - 6066
  ports:
    - 6066:6066
    - 7077:7077 # Master (Main Port)
    - 8080:8080 # Web UI
    #- 7006:7006 # Executor

sparkworker:
  extra_hosts:
    - driver:192.168.99.100
  image: gettyimages/spark
  command: /usr/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker -h sparkworker spark://sparkmaster:7077
#  volumes:
#    - ./spark/logs:/log/spark
  hostname: sparkworker
  environment:
    SPARK_CONF_DIR: /conf
    SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 4
    SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 4g
    SPARK_WORKER_PORT: 8881
    SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT: 8081
    SPARK_LOCAL_IP: 192.168.99.100
    #SPARK_MASTER_OPTS: "-Dspark.driver.port=7001 -Dspark.fileserver.port=7002 -Dspark.broadcast.port=7003 -Dspark.replClassServer.port=7004 -Dspark.blockManager.port=7005 -Dspark.executor.port=7006 -Dspark.ui.port=4040 -Dspark.broadcast.factory=org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory"
    SPARK_JAVA_OPTS:  "-Dspark.broadcast.factory=org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory"
    SPARK_MASTER_OPTS: "-Dspark.broadcast.factory=org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory"
    SPARK_WORKER_OPTS: "-Dspark.driver.port=7001 -Dspark.fileserver.port=7002 -Dspark.broadcast.port=7003 -Dspark.replClassServer.port=7004 -Dspark.blockManager.port=15003 -Dspark.executor.port=7006 -Dspark.ui.port=4040 -Dspark.broadcast.factory=org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory"
    #SPARK_JAVA_OPTS: "-Dspark.driver.port=7001 -Dspark.fileserver.port=7002 -Dspark.broadcast.port=7003 -Dspark.replClassServer.port=7004 -Dspark.blockManager.port=7005 -Dspark.executor.port=7006 -Dspark.ui.port=4040 -Dspark.broadcast.factory=org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory"
  links:
    - sparkmaster
  expose:
    - 7001
    - 7002
    - 7003
    - 7004
    - 7005
    - 7006
    - 7012
    - 7013
    - 7014
    - 7015
    - 7016
    - 8881
  ports:
    - 8081:8081 # WebUI
    #- 15003:15003 # Blockmanager+
    - 7005:7005 # Executor
    - 7006:7006 # Executor
    #- 7006:7006 # Executor
```

I even don't really know anymore which port is actually used etc.. What I know is that my current problem is the following. Driver can communicate to Master, Master can communicate with Worker, i think the Driver can communicate with the worker HOWEVER!!! the driver can't communicate with the / an executor. I also identified the problem. When I open the application UI and open the exectuors tab, then it shows "Executor 0  - Address 172.17.0.1:7005".

So the problem is, that the driver addresses the executor with the Docker gateway address, which does not work. I tried several things (SPARK_LOCAL_IP, using explicit hostnames etc.), but the driver always tries to communicate with the Docker Gateway... Any ideas how to achieve that the driver can communicate with the executor / worker?

Comment: Do all of these components need ports exposed on the host? If not, why not use links between containers that only need to communicate locally? This would cut down a lot on exposed ports. It sounds like the master needs to listen on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). But I was able to dig up https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4389 which makes it sound like this isn't possible.

Comment: Currently it is just a test, even with links it doesn't seem to work. However I'd like to not use links, because later on I want to distribute the components on different vms. With this test i just wanted to find out which ports need to be public etc.. But I don't get it and I think the spark docs are a mess. There are so many options you could set to override ports which are not documented well:/

Comment: Until Spark can support binding to all interfaces using 0.0.0.0, I don't think this will work the way you intend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to insufficient configuration options provided by Spark. Spark binds to listen on `SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME` and it propagates this exact hostname to the cluster. Unfortunately, this setup does not work if driver is behind NAT, for example a Docker container.

You can work around this with the following setup (I've used this hack successfully):

- forward all necessary ports 1-to-1 (as you do)
- use a custom hostname for the driver: set e.g. `SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME: mydriver`
- for master and worker nodes, add `192.168.99.100 mydriver` to `/etc/hosts`, so that they can reach the Spark driver.
- for the docker container, map `mydriver` to `0.0.0.0`. This will make the Spark driver bind to `0.0.0.0`, so it will be reachable by master and workers:

To do that in docker-compose.yml, simply add the following lines:

```
 extra_hosts:
  - "mydriver:0.0.0.0"
```